# Menu Driven Java Program to implement Binary Search Tree. Cant get the Tree structure to add nodes beyond the root (insert function)

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Beyond the root, I couldn't add any more nodes permanently. Once a tree object is created in the insert function, on the next entry into the insert function it is being nullified, so only root is present. I can't find the problem and it's driving me crazy. Someone please help, it would be preferable if you use the same data structures I used in this code.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class tree

    { 
          int x;

           tree left=null;

        tree right=null;
     }

       class bst28
        {
           public static tree root=null;

            public static void main(String[] args)
            {  
               bst28 bl=new bst28();
               int ch,y;
                 Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
               do{
                   System.out.println("Menu:\n1.Insert\n2.Search");   System.out.println("\n3.In-order-traversal\n4..Exit:");
                 ch=scn.nextInt();
                switch(ch)
                 {
                  case 1:System.out.println("Enter the element to insert :");
                 y=scn.nextInt();
                 bl.insert(y);
                     break;
          case 2:System.out.println("Enter the element to search for :");
                y=scn.nextInt();
                bl.search(y);
                     break;
          case 3:  bl.inorder(bl.root);
                     break;

          default:break;  
       }
      }while(ch!=4);

   }

        void insert(int a) 
        {
            tree temp=new tree();
           temp.x=a;
            boolean val=true;
            if(root==null)
            {  
               root=new tree();
                 root=temp;

          return;
       }
        System.out.println(root.x);
       tree current=new tree();
       current=root;
       while(val)
        {
           if(a<current.x)
            { System.out.println(current.x);
                 System.out.println("Trav to left");
              current=current.left;
              if(current==null)
               {  
                     System.out.println("Node currently null");
                  current=new tree();
                  current=temp;
                  System.out.println("Entered left of a node");
                  System.out.println(current.x);
                  val=false;
                }
            }
           else if(a>current.x)
             {
               System.out.println("Trav to right");
             current=current.right;
              if(current==null)
               {  
                  System.out.println("Node currently null");
                 current=new tree();
                 current=temp;
                 System.out.println("Entered right of a node");
                 System.out.println(current.x);
                  val=false;
                }
              }
              else
                 {
                   System.out.println("Value exists in the tree\n");
                   val=false;
                 }
        }
      }

         void search(int a)
           {
               if(root==null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Empty tree !");
                    return;   

                 } 

                 tree current=new tree();
                  current=root;
                  while(current!=null)
                   {
                       if(a==current.x)
                         {
                           System.out.println("FOund !");
                            return;               
                           }
                           else if(a<current.x)
                           {
                           current=current.left;
                          }
                        else
                       {
                          current=current.right;
                        }   

                   } 
               System.out.println("Not Found !");
            } 

          void inorder(tree temp)
          {
             if(temp!=null)
            {
               inorder(temp.left);
                  System.out.println("Visited node :"+temp.x);
               inorder(temp.right);
               }

             }



          }`
```

Comment: Please post actual code that passes compilation, and some decent indentation would also help.

Comment: In Java: the names of your classes should start with a capital letter (this won't solve your problem, but it is something you should learn to do)

Comment: @Eran the code i posted compiled perfectly, no errors .

Comment: @LisaMM point taken. Im not a java coder though , its just for my data structures lab at college

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not associating the new subtree (let's call it "node" because it contains only 1 element) to the existing tree. You are creating the node, moving down the tree, and when you find that the current node is null associate the new node to the current. You got to stay one step ahead, meaning: before moving down the tree (to the left or right) check if the (left/right) subtree is null or not and act accordingly.
So, the code:

```
if(a<current.x)
    { System.out.println(current.x);
         System.out.println("Trav to left");
      current=current.left;
      if(current==null)
       {  
             System.out.println("Node currently null");
          current=new tree();
          current=temp;
          System.out.println("Entered left of a node");
          System.out.println(current.x);
          val=false;
        }
    }
```

becomes something like this (I have not run the code, so test it):

```
if(a<current.x)
    { System.out.println(current.x);
         System.out.println("Trav to left");

      if(current.left!=null)
      {
          current=current.left;
          System.out.println("Entered left of a node");
          System.out.println(current.x);
      } 
      else
       {  
             System.out.println("Node currently null");
          current.left=temp;
          val=false;
        }
    }
```

The same must be done for the other case.